# Does magento 2 send invoice email?

Tags: magento2, invoice

Does magento 2 send email automatically when order has been paid (and invoice is created) ?

Mine doesnt. Can't understand how or where.

Comment: Can you please share which specific online payment method you are using on your store?

Comment: Paypal for example.